# Inconsistent line-height between INPUT and LABEL

Tags: html, css

Why would setting `line-height` to match `font-size` cause this strange behavior:

The height of `label` is 16px but `input` is 18px... Why?

The heights will suddenly match if I change `line-height: 18px` or higher. What is happening?

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3cru8fv0/2/)

```
<style>
label, input {

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border: none;            
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<form>
    <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" />      
</form>
```

Chrome v36 screenshots showing the 16/18px height difference and no `border`, `margin`, or `padding`:
[image: Label - 16px height]
[image: Input - 18px height]

Comment: Interesting. If you don't specify a line-height, both will be 18px. The input isn't being affected by the line-height rule (try changing it to .5em.)

Comment: If you look closely, the text input adds a 1px padding on the bottom and top of the input's inside typing area. May be a default browser's behaviour... So, actually, the `line-height`'s are equal.

Comment: Chrome inspector shows there is no border, padding or margin. Since the `line-height`'s are both set to 16px, what is causing the height to be different.

Comment: Type some text on the input, and hover it with the inspector... You'll see that there's a higher padding on the input's text... It is not due to line-height...

Comment: In Chrome Inspector, it says `padding-top: 0` for both elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> On replaced inline elements, like buttons or other input element,
>   line-height has no effect.

If you remove the line-height, both elements will have a computed height of 18px. By setting the line-height to the font-size (and fyi, typically line-height is set to a unit-less value for example 1 would be equal to 1x the font-size.) By setting it to 16px, it is actually restricting the height based on the default line-height, from 18px, it's natural height, to 16px, the line-height constrained value. If you set the line-height to .5, [you'll notice the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/3cru8fv0/5/) more dramatically:

```
input, label {
    line-height: .5;
    background: #eee;
}
input {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Starting to make sense. Do I have this right?: The `font-size` is 16px which actually makes the default `line-height` 18px. When reducing `line-height` below its default, the label overflows up in space above whereas the `input` ignores a `line-height` smaller than the default size. So what it comes down to is the `input` allows `line-height` to be larger than default, and gets larger with it, but not smaller.

Comment: Yeah - it's odd that it allows the input to get larger, but not smaller, but that pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confused about what `line-height` represents in CSS. It actually determines line spacing in a paragraph, not the actual height of the corresponding HTML control.

FYI, the difference is height is caused by the 1px border which is present in the input but is absent in the label.

Comment: Try changing the line-height in my example and you will see it does change the height. http://jsfiddle.net/3cru8fv0/3/

Comment: Yep, it may increase padding inside the control, but for that you should really be using `padding` or `height` CSS properties, not `line-height`. `line-height` serves a completely different purpose. Look it up on the web.

Comment: Look at my screenshots -- there is no border.

Comment: @Justin uncoder is correct. Try removing `line-height` from the CSS.

Comment: My question is why does the line-height when set to 16px for both present a different height for each. What causes the difference? Unicoder is arguing that line-hight is not height... which I understand and am not asking about.

Comment: It's not because of padding or borders.