# How to vertical align icon inside label and button in the same way

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center vertically an icon inside an ul/li tag.
Depending if placing the icon inside a button tag and label tag I get two different results and I can not get the alignment in the label working.

```
<ul>
    <li><label class="btn"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></label></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></button></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}

button,
label{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
 outline: none;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

  button:hover,
  label:hover{
  background-color: #4E84BB;
  color: white;
}
```

Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbhjco0j/

How do I center the icon in both scenario?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD `line-height: 41px;` to `button, label` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zbhjco0j/1/)**

CSS:

```
button,
label{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    line-height: 41px;   /* newly added */
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I mark it as correct answer but why the label is not working as the button without the line-height prop?

Comment: you can get more idea here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height 
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537989/inconsistent-line-height-between-input-and-label